# shared memory between parent and child in c

Tags: c, posix, shared-memory, fibonacci

I am writing a program using fork() that generates sequence of  Fibonacci, so that if i passed 8 in a command line the output being :
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21
and have this output

next step I'am trying to make it shared between parent and child using Posix shared memory, but the data not shared between them, this is my code:

```
      pid = fork();
      if (pid == 0)
      {  /* create the shared memory object */
     shm_fib = shm_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);

     /* configure the size of the shared memory object */
     ftruncate(shm_fib, SIZE);
     /* memory map the shared memory object */
     ptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fib, 0);
         printf("Child is producing the Fibonacci Sequence...\n");
         sprintf(ptr,"%d, %d,",f1,f2);
         ptr++;
         for (i=2;i<n;i++)
         {
            sum=f1+f2;
            sprintf(ptr,"%d, ", sum);
            ptr++;
            f1=f2;
            f2=sum;
         }
         printf("Child ends\n"); 
      }
      else 
      {  wait(NULL);
         /* open the shared memory object */
         shm_fib = shm_open(name, O_RDONLY, 0666); 

         if (shm_fib == -1) 
         {

        printf("shared memory failed\n");

        exit(-1);

     }
     /* memory map the shared memory object */
     ptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm_fib, 0);
         printf("Parent is waiting for child to complete...\n");

         /* read from the shared memory object */
     printf("%s",(char *)ptr);
     /* remove the shared memory object */
     shm_unlink(name);
         printf("Parent ends\n");
      }
```

and this is the output:

```
plz, Enter the value of number to show the fibonacci sequence:
9
Child is producing the Fibonacci Sequence...
Child ends
shared memory failed
```

anyone can help me to know why the memory shared is failed?!?

Comment: You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Always print out the `errno` or call `perror` to see the exact error. That will tell you the error is "No such file or directory". And that is caused by the `shm_unlink` at the end of the code. That `shm_unlink` can be (and often is) executed by the child before the parent has had a chance to complete its usage of the shared memory. And in case it is not obvious, the man page says about `shm_unlink`:

> After a successful shm_unlink(),  attempts  to  shm_open() an object 
>   with  the same name will fail

Suggest you just remove that code. Don't think it is needed as the parent process code already has a (more valid) `shm_unlink`.

Update: In fact, that `shm_unlink` is guaranteed to be executed before the parent uses the shared memory. Because the parent (correctly) has a `wait` for the child to complete.

Comment: thanks alot, but the problem still appear until I change the shm_unlink,, so i'am try to change  sprintf statement in the parent process from:  sprintf(ptr,"%d, %d,",f1,f2);
         ptr++; to be separate for each value and it's correct shared

Answer (score 2):

As you're forking but not exec-ing, you can simply `mmap` an `MAP_ANONYMOUS` (or using `/dev/zero`) `MAP_SHARED` mapping before forking. The region will be shared between both processes:

```
// Error handling omitted for brevity
void* ptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
  // [...] Write the shared memory
} else {
  wait(NULL);
  // [...] Read the shared memory
}
```